# Slide out/in (show/hide) animation for complete window

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a Windows TrayIcon application. When the user clicks on the tray icon, my WPF window gets shown. If the user closes the window it gets simply hidden. On the next click on the tray icon, the same window gets shown again.

The goal is now to have the appearance of the window animated. The window should "slide up" from the taskbar. And it should "slide down" when the user closes the window. I currently have a solution which I does not really like and I am wondering if there is better way. I have an animation which changes the height of the Layout Container (grid in this case):

```
<Storyboard x:Key="BottomUpSlideIn" Completed="BottomUpSlideIn_OnCompleted">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="470"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

But it does actually not hide the window, it just sets its height to zero. Is it possible to set the visibility of the Window to hidden after the animation is done? Or do you know a different/better approach to get this done?

Comment: You could animate the `Opacity`(/`Visibilily`) simulaneously.

Comment: I'm really not an expert in this. How could I do this? Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

I used this on one of my first applications... you may need to adjust the `Trigger` to your requirements:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="SlideStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation Name="SlideDoubleAnimation" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="SlideWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Top"
                    Duration="0:0:0.75" Completed="SlideDoubleAnimation_Completed" 
                    AccelerationRatio="0.5" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

`SlideWindow` is the value of the `Window.Name` property.

Then for the closing animation, I just adjusted this `DoubleAnimation` object:

```
private void BeginCloseAnimation()
{
    SlideDoubleAnimation.From = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - 
        this.Height - 2;
    SlideDoubleAnimation.To = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;        
    SlideStoryboard.Begin();
    close = true;
}

private void SlideDoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (close) Close();
}
```

Comment: Can I change Visibility after the animation is finished? Because I want to hide the Window (instead of closing it)

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not... give it a go.